# Errors in a simple capture program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying a simple program but a error is coming . I don't know what it is? In the error it is showing as
warning : error opening file

My program

```
#include<opencv/cvaux.h>
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include<opencv/cxcore.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
     cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture(" F://dc//dc++//Bryan Adams - Summer of 69 (Live).avi" );
     IplImage* frame;

     while(1) {
          frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

          if( !frame ) break;

          cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
          char c = cvWaitKey(33);

          if( c == 27 ) break;
     }
     cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
     cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
}
```

Comment: " F://dc//dc++//Bryan Adams - Summer of 69 (Live).avi" is *soooo* wrong ;( remove the blank at the start, replace "//" by "/"  (also, change the content, bryan adams, really ?)

Comment: but that was working for displaying a image..and with after doing what you had said same error is coming.

Comment: just check while ( capture != 0 ) { ...

Comment: also, could you try *not* to use the deprecated c-api ?

Comment: warning : error opening file <c:\users\vp\work\ocv\opencv\modules\highgui\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp:454>        That's the error coming every tme in command video.

Comment: yea, it just means, it could not find/load your file - your path is wrong

Comment: My path is correct, i checked it properly just now.

Comment: I am just a beginner and learning from Oreilly-learning opencv.

Comment: What is deprecated c-api ?

Comment: cvLoadImage, IplImages, avoid that, it won't be supported for long. use cv::Mat , cv::imread(), etc

Comment: What can i do now to run the program?